# Time complexity and space complexity of the following piece of code

Tags: c, function, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

```
double foo(int n)
{
    int i;
    double sum;
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += foo(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

I've figured out the space complexity of this function i.e O(n) but i'm stuck how to calculate time complexity. I've also made the Recursion tree to find Space complexity but unable to calculate how to calculate time complexity. Can somebody help me to understand it and visualize it.

[image]

here is the recursion tree.

Answer (score 3):

The graph you've presented is very helpful for visualizing the time scaling of the algorithm.  Consider this question: what is the relationship between the recursion trees T<sub>*n*</sub> and T<sub>*n*+1</sub> for inputs *n* and *n*+1?  Or equivalently, given T<sub>*n*</sub>, how can T<sub>*n*+1</sub> be constructed?

It should be clear both from the structure of the algorithm and from the depiction of its recursion tree that T<sub>*n*</sub> for *n* > 0 is composed of all the T<sub>*i*</sub>, 0 <= *i* < *n*, all joined through one additional node.  With a bit of additional thought you should be able to see that one can construct T<sub>*n*+1</sub> by this procedure:

- make a copy, T', of T<sub>*n*</sub>
- increment the value the root of T' by one
- make the root of T<sub>*n*</sub> a child of the root of T' to form T<sub>*n*+1</sub>

By that construction, T<sub>*n*+1</sub> has twice as many nodes as T<sub>*n*</sub>, so the time complexity scales as O(2<sup>*n*</sup>).

You've already answered your own question about the space complexity, but I affirm that it corresponds to the height of the tree, and thus scales as O(*n*).

Comment: Okay @John Bollinger if we use 1-D array to store result of function call like Dynamic Programming concept to reduce the Function call then also Space Complexity will be O(n) for Array and O(1) for Stack but here what will be the time complexity?

Comment: What are your thoughts on that, @SanjayVerma?  What work does a call `foo(N)` then perform?